# WSL not working after system image restore

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I recently had to backup and restore my Windows OS and data from a system image. Everything seems to be working fine, except for WSL. Whenever I try to start up my WSL Ubuntu distribution, I get the following error:

```
The operation timed out because a response was not received from the virtual machine or container.

[process exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)]
```

I tried installing the Kali Linux distribution, but that also hung at startup, albeit, without any error message. Additionally, I was thinking of exporting my WSL Ubuntu distribution, uninstalling it, disabling/re-enabling WSL, and then re-importing, but I'm not even able to run `wsl --export Ubuntu ubuntu.tar`.

Any ideas on what the issue might be and how to fix it?

###### Additional Info

```
$ wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         2
```

```
$ wsl --status
Default Distribution: Ubuntu
Default Version: 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 4/18/2022
WSL automatic updates are on.

Kernel version: 5.10.102.1
```

Comment: Sounds like the file was deleted have you tried to reinstall it?

Comment: I did try re-installing WSL and replacing the ext4.vhdx file with that of my original (malfunctioning) instance of Ubuntu, but it did not work. However, a new install of Ubuntu worked fine for some reason, so I ended up deciding to recover my data from the vhdx file instead, and am in the process of setting up my dev environment again. In case it helps anyone, [here](https://christopherkibble.com/posts/wsl-vhdx-recovery/) are the instructions I followed to recover my data from the vhdx file.